# My app crashes when going to settings from app,permissions changed in settings and returning back to app

Tags: java, android

An activity which appears after 3 other activities in my app, requires storage permission (for choosing a file) and thus, checks if the app has the permission, before I can choose a file.
So, to test this, on reaching this activity with storage permission already given, I go to settings ,toggle the permission state and come back to the app.
The same activity is launched but crashes a second later showing NullPointerException on parts of code where i am using a variable sent from a previous activity with its intent.

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.camera);
        pictureSettings = (Picture) ((ApplicationContext) this.getApplication()).map.get(Objects.requireNonNull(getIntent().getExtras()).getInt("Sequence"));
        setOrientation(pictureSettings.getOrientation()); //getOrientation function gives error - java.lang.String com.example.Picture.getOrientation()
    }
```

Crash log

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.app}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int com.flow.PictureClass.getOrientation()' on a null object reference.
```

Comment: Could you post your crash log?

Comment: I've put up the crash logs @Rohit5k2

Comment: `pictureScreenParameters` is null, probably because your intent data is lost when you went settings. Save your data before going to setting and restore when you come back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apps would be killed when permission was toggled, and when you switch back, it would try to restart the last activity **without** starting the underlaying activities that were previously started. In your case, your fourth activity was restarted but the 3 old activities were not.

And from your code, I saw that your activity needs some data that should have been initialized **before** the activity started:

```
pictureScreenParameters = (PictureScreenClass)((ApplicationContext) this.getApplication()).flowMap.get(Objects.requireNonNull(getIntent().getExtras()).getInt("Sequence"))
```

Well this may be considered bad practice. When Android restarted your activity, `pictureScreenParameters` is not initialized and is obviously `null`.

Advice:
 1. Check if `pictureScreenParameters` is null before using it. If it's null, try to initialize it or use default values.
 2. On newer Android verions (6.0+) you should request storage and other permissions at runtime: [Request permissions at runtime appropriately](https://developer.android.com/distribute/best-practices/develop/runtime-permissions) .

Comment: Other answers mentioned the same problem earlier but this is the reason to it~

Answer (score 0):

You must need to check that

`getIntent.getextras(Bundle)` is not null before

```
pictureScreenParameters = (PictureScreenClass) ((ApplicationContext) this.getApplication())
          .flowMap.get(Objects.requireNonNull(getIntent().getExtras()).getInt("Sequence"));
```

and if it is null debug app ,may be u r using wrong context ,

Answer (score 0):

Of course yes, in some cases `getExtras()` may return `null`, no longer intent data available. When your activity starts, it expects some data sent from  the previous activity with `putExtras()` method but from **Settings** it has not been sent and you didn't save the instance.

You have to check that, starting by checking the returned intent and its extended data:

```java
Bundle extras=null;

Intent intent = getIntent(); 

if(intent!=null){
  extras=intent.getExtras()
}
```

Then before use, test if extras is not null. Just because you are not sure that your activity will always start/resume/restart after the activity that sends extras.

About requesting permissions, I think it's better to test permission and request it directly inside the activity programmatically instead of switching to **settings** and add manually.